# How to run npm 'filestream' example code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, filestream

I'm planning to use file stream api in the browser. By searching, I found this filestream module.

https://github.com/DamonOehlman/filestream

The author wrote a example usage code. Here it is. (File name : drag-n-drop.js)

```
var crel = require('crel');
var detect = require('feature/detect');
var dnd = require('drag-and-drop-files');
var img = crel('img');
var video = crel('video', { autoplay: true });
var FileReadStream = require('filestream/read');
var FileWriteStream = require('filestream/write');

function upload(files) {
  var queue = [].concat(files);

  function sendNext() {
    var writer = new FileWriteStream();
    var next = queue.shift();

    console.log('sending file');
    new FileReadStream(next).pipe(writer).on('file', function(file) {
      console.log('file created: ', file);
      img.src = detect('URL').createObjectURL(file);
      // video.src = detect('URL').createObjectURL(next);

      if (queue.length > 0) {
        sendNext();
      }
    });
  }

  sendNext();
}

dnd(document.body, upload);

document.body.appendChild(crel('style', 'body, html { margin: 0; width: 100%; height: 100% }'));
document.body.appendChild(img);
document.body.appendChild(video);
```

  1.

In this code... I'm totally frustrated. 
Which side this code works for? Server side? Or client side code?

If server side code, where is the create-server methods and how document.body.~  codes are read?

If client side code, how to use 'require' method in the browser?

Most of all, is this runnable code?

  2.

Putting aside the previous questions, I tried to run this code. To do that, I installed 'crel', 'feature', 'drag-and-drop-files' modules, and give command : `$node drag-n-drop.js`

But, it doesn't works, and the error message is like this. This also frustrate me...

```
[appPath]/node_modules/crel/crel.js:91
        element = crel[isElementString](element) ? element : d.createElement(e
                                                               ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at crel ([appPath]/node_modules/crel/crel.js:91:64)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([appPath]/node_modules/filestream/examples/drag-n-drop.js:4:11)
```

Help!

Update. 3.

Hey. Can I ask you one more question? I'm adapting the filestream module to my code, referencing with the above example code. While doing, I got stuck in the `detect('URL')` code. I read the 'feature' module in the npm page and read the description carefully, but I still can't understand that. Refer to this page link , I don't know why author use `detect('URL')`, rather than `window.URL`. Can you explain it? I really appreciate with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1:

`document.body` usually is a `window` object's property, so the example is for client side. Or you can use some module, for example: [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom). Then you can use window in node.

`require` is a function in [CommonJS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) module specifications. you can use [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/) to compile it for client side.

Question 2:

As above, you should use CommonJS module build tool or use jsdom for server side.

`createElement` is a method on `window.document`.

**Update:**

Question 3:

`require('feature/detect');`

will require [detect.js](https://github.com/DamonOehlman/feature/blob/master/detect.js) in `feature` npm module

As you can see, it tests `ms`, `o`, `moz`, `webkit` prefixs with target feature on window.

In the bottom of below link, there is a `Browser compatibility` table.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/URL

In Chrome 8.0, Opera 15.0 and Safari 6.0 `URL` exists as `webkitURL`.

This is why author do that.

Comment: Wow... this is what I really wanted answer! Thanks!

Comment: Hey. Can I ask you one more question? I'm adapting the filestream module to my code, referencing with the above example code. While doing, I got stuck in the  `detect('URL')` code. I read the 'feature' module in the npm page and read the description carefully, but I still can't understand that. Refer to this page [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) , I don't know why author use `detect('URL')`, rather than `window.URL`. Can you explain it? I really appreciate with you...

Comment: Wow....... I really really thanks to you. I read that detect.js source code before ask you a new question, but can't understand then. But after your answer, I finally got understand it. Thank you!